# How to represent Django money field with currency symbol in list template and plain decimal for edits?

Tags: django, templates, form-fields

When I display money in a list template or detail (read-only) template I would like to be able to display a pretty version of the field's value which includes the currency symbol: "$100.00"

However, when the record is being edited, I would like to display "100.00" in the TextInput box without any currency symbol.

I made a custom models.DecimalField class and forms.DecimalField class to represent money in my Django application.

So I'm trying to come up with a way to have an alternate version of the field's value in the template that is pretty (i.e. properly formatted for viewing but not ideal for editing).  I know there are template filters that let you accomplish this, but I believe that would prevent me from iterating through the fields in a form and displaying their values.

If I can add a pretty attribute to my custom field class, I can check if it exists in the template and display it.  So far I tried this:

```
class MoneyFormField(forms.DecimalField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # I plan to add symbol localization code here
        self.symbol= '$'

    def prepare_value(self, value):
        # assign pretty value to an attribute that template can access
        self.pretty = self.pretty_value(value)            
        try:
            return round(Decimal(value),2)
        except:
            return 0

    def pretty_value(self, value):
        if not value:
            value = 0
        return self.symbol + str(round(Decimal(value),2))
```

The problem is that in order to access the pretty value in the template, I have to access the original value first so that prepare_value() is called.

If I try to print the pretty value in a template like this...

```
{% for field in payment_form %}
    {{ field.field.pretty }} {{ field.value }} {{ field.field.pretty }} 
{% endfor %}
```

then the first pretty is ignored, but the last pretty prints.

If I can get this to work then I would display a pretty value (or default value if pretty doesn't exist) in a template like this:

```
{% if field.field.pretty %}
    {{ field.field.pretty}}
{% else %}
    {{ field.value }}
{% endif %}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for making an alternate representation of a field available to a template?

TL;DR- How can I access the field's value in the form field's **init** ?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution but since I'm new to Django and python I might be making things unnecessarily over-complicated.  So I'd love to hear any feedback!

To summarize: I wanted my money fields to have a "pretty" version that can display money as "$100.00" instead of "100.00" in certain templates like lists and read-only details.

I created a money model field that specifies my custom form field, MoneyFormField:

```
class MoneyField(models.DecimalField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_digits'] = 13
        kwargs['decimal_places'] = 4
        kwargs['default'] = 0

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': MoneyFormField}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(MoneyField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

Here is my MoneyFormField form field.  Note the call to "get_bound_field":

```
class MoneyFormField(forms.DecimalField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.widget = MoneyTextInput() # custom widget I'm experimenting with
        self.prefix = '$'            
        super(MoneyFormField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_bound_field(self, form, field_name):
        return MoneyBoundField(form, self, field_name)        

    def prepare_value(self, value):
        try:
            return round(Decimal(value),2)
        except:
            return 0
```

MoneyBoundField is what makes the "pretty" version of the field available to the template:

```
class MoneyBoundField(BoundField):
    def pretty(self):
        return self.field.prefix+str(self.value())
```

If I just did this then I could print pretty values by first checking if a pretty value existed, and if not, printing the original value like this:

```
{% for somefield in payment_form %}
    {% if somefield.pretty %}
        {{ somefield.pretty }}
    {% else %}
        {{ somefield.value }}
    {% endif %}    
{% endfor %}
```

But I would rather just do something like this:

```
{% for somefield in payment_form %}
    {{ somefield.pretty }}
{% endfor %}
```

So I had to add pretty to the main Django BoundField class in boundfields.py by adding the two lines:

```
boundfield.py
class BoundField(object):
...
    def pretty(self):
        # return default value.  Let descendant classes override this function where desired
        return self.value()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach I took.  Instead of messing with the main django BoundField class definition in boundfield.py, I'm now just using a template filter to make the field pretty.  The filter does the following:

- If the field is a choice field, it converts the choice index value to the description string
- If the field has a custom formfield, with a custom BoundField, with a function called "pretty" it calls that function and returns the value.
- (commented out) you can attempt to call a specific method in your custom formfield class if applicable.  This eliminates the need to define a BoundField in your formfield class
- If these don't apply it just returns the field's value unmodified

This is the code in my app_filters.py:

```
from django.forms.fields import ChoiceField

@register.filter
def pretty_filter(field):
    # is this a better way to get the field's value?
    # field_value = field.form.initial[field.name]

    # get the field's value (for choice fields, this is the integer index used to look up the verbose string in the choices dict)
    field_value = field.value()
    if field_value is None:
        return ''
    # the the field has 'choices' then return the verbose string for the choice
    if isinstance(field.field, ChoiceField): 
        for (choices_index, description) in field.field.choices: 
            if choices_index == field_value: 
                return description
        return '' # no match found

    # # if your model.field's formfield has a function called
    # # another_custom_function() you can call it this way:
    # try:
    #     return field.field.another_custom_function()
    # except:
    #     pass

    # attempt to return pretty value if field has th
    try:
        return field.pretty()
    except:
    # else return default value
        return field_value
```

I also made a change to my custom money field's pretty function so it adds a comma (this could be changed to handle localization):

```
class MoneyBoundField(BoundField):    
    def pretty(self):
        # return $12,345.67
        return "{}{:,.2f}".format(self.field.prefix,self.value())

class MoneyFormField(forms.DecimalField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.widget = MoneyTextInput()
        self.prefix = '$'
        super(MoneyFormField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_bound_field(self, form, field_name):
        return MoneyBoundField(form, self, field_name)
```

Then in my template I used it like this:

```
{% load app_filters %}

{% for item in payment_form %}
    {{item|pretty_filter}}
{% endfor %}
```

Much of the filter code is copied from user Simple10 here:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10427#comment:18

Please share any thoughts or comments!