# Django: Simple solution to prepend $ to form field

Tags: django, django-forms, currency

I would like to prepend a $ to an input field for a few of my forms. I don't want the $ sent to the backend as part of the input value. I have found a few stack overflow questions that suggest things like the updates below:

```
self.fields['buy_price'].localize = True
self.fields['buy_price'].widget.is_localized = True
self.fields['buy_price'].prefix = '$'
```

But none of these are working for me. I also would prefer to avoid adding 50+ lines of code, such as recommended in this S.O. Answer: [How to represent Django money field with currency symbol in list template and plain decimal for edits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214746/how-to-represent-django-money-field-with-currency-symbol-in-list-template-and-pl)

**HTML form:**

```
{% url 'update-buy/' offer.id as buy_update_url %}
<form method="POST" action="{{ buy_update_url }}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Update Offer to Buy a Game</legend>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                    {{ form.media }}
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="hidden_desired_game_id" name="hidden_desired_game" value="{{ offer.desired_game_id }}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button onclick="clearMessage()" class="post-button btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**Does anyone have a simple way to do this?**

**UPDATE:**

I updated to use `{% crispy form %}` instead of {{ form|crispy }}, which is nicely showing the $. But now, the hidden input with `id="hidden_desired_game_id"` is not included in the POST request. For some reason, when rendering the form (screenshot below), that input is now BELOW the form, not inside it. **Any idea how I can still have that included?**

[image]

**EDIT #2: I fixed the above problem by moving the input field higher up in the form. But now it looks like jquery is loading twice or something. There are 2 dropdown arrows on the right side of the Desired game field and it looks ugly. I tried using javascript to manipulate the class and played around with the `css_class` feature from crispy-forms, but i can't get it to only have one dropdown. Does anyone know how to fix that? Screenshot below**

[image]

**SOLUTION FOUND: FINAL UPDATE:**

I was able to fix the above issue of 2 dropdowns by adding this javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {
            $( ".custom-select" ).removeClass("custom-select"); // Remove dupe dropdown
```

}

Kinda hacky but oh well! Everything is good now

Comment: How about [boostrap input group adon](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#basic-example)

Comment: @Sumithran I was looking at that, it would be perfect. But I don't have access to the input field in my html form / template. I added the form to  my question to show what i mean. I even tried using Javascript to get Django's input element by id and manipulating the html, but couldn't get that to work, and it seems hacky anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [Bootstrap Layout objects](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html#bootstrap-layout-objects)

forms.py

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import PrependedText

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            PrependedText('buy_price', '$')
        )
```

instead of `{{ form|crispy }}` you have to use `{% crispy form %}`

The form field will look like

[image: boostrap input group adon django]

Comment: This works and it looks great, but for some reason it stopped the form from actually submitting and doing the POST request. any idea why this code change would cause that?

Comment: Okay, I guess the problem is with that onclick() method, instead of onclick as inline attribute, you can use something like ```$('button-id-here').onclick( fn body here)``` inside your script.

Comment: I updated my question with info about a hidden input element not being included, for some reason it was moved outside of the form element when rendered. Any idea what might cause that?

Comment: Have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/q/54353158/6562458

Comment: Thanks I fixed that problem, but now there are 2 dropdown icons in the Desired game field (I updated the question with info). How can i make it so there's only 1 dropdown arrow?

Comment: Found the solution, updated my answer to show it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wow, glad to help you.